# Likes and Facebook Apps

Tags: facebook, web-applications

I have an application in facebook. I want to add one of the pages on my site to facebook user like list, so if he clicked "I like" on my web page. Can I do it programmatically?

Comment: May be I did not describe the issue correctly. I want programmatically make a click using user account that is using my facebook application. Can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the Facebook developer pages to be really informative. Check them out!

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/04/adding-facebook-like-buttons-to-your-site-is-damn-easy/

Answer (score 0):

With your update it sounds like you are trying to make the user like your page against their will.  This is not allowed by Facebook and there is no api to force a user to like your page.  They must click your like button - you cannot click it for them.  Although I have seen some spam sites that have found flaws that allow you to do this.  Also other spam sites will do clickjacking - where they overlay other buttons over top of the facebook like buttons and trick users into clicking them.  However this is one of the fastest ways to get your apps and accounts banned from Facebook.